# Coimarketcap api data different from coinmarketcap.com

Tags: api, coinmarketcap-com, request

I am using popular Coinmarketcap API request:

```
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?limit=100&convert=ETH
```

In response `percentChangeFor24h` and some other parameters are always different from what is show on coinmarketcap.com. Do I miss something or data is just irrelevant? Could it be from timezone? I have not found any way to change timezone into requests itself.

Comment: If you go to the coinmarketcap.com site and reload the page several times at about 1 second apart you'll see that the volume does not change. This means there's a cache, since there's definitely thousands of trades every second. The API, on the other hand, is probably not cached. This must be the source of the difference you see.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the update frequency of the API and website.

They certainly use the same source to get data for their website and API.

One might be lagging a few minutes sometimes. I'd assume the API data is the most up to date and it's safe to rely on it.